# tqdm print average information in the end of the loop

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torch, tqdm

During the run tqdm print current information of the unit (in my case batch) like accuracy and loss.

Is there an elegant way that after last iteration tqdm print in the same line the average accuracy/loss of all the batches that run?

Now I'm doing in "manually" by saving the accuracy/loss data for each batch and apply mean when the loop finish.

Comment: If it can help, there are two repositories ([1](https://github.com/IgorSusmelj/pytorch-styleguide) and [2](https://github.com/victoresque/pytorch-template) that are quite useful at summarizing best practices using pytorch and tqdm. I am thinking particularly about [this line](https://github.com/IgorSusmelj/pytorch-styleguide/blob/master/cifar10-example/cifar10_example.py#L187C1-L187C65) for your question, even though it is probably very close to what you are doing.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Is your question about computing the running metrics? or rather about how to show those metrics on the tqdm bar after each iteration?

Comment: @Ivan, Now I do in manually and it's working, I mean after each batch I keep the data and apply mean in the end of the loop and print the result. I know how to compute and show the result. The question is it possible by tqdm to do both of the steps (calculation and printing) in an elegant way?

Comment: You could maybe look into [torchmetrics](https://www.google.com/search?q=torchmetrics&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:fr:{referrer:source}&ie=UTF-8&oe=)

Comment: Hi, I made a repository for this kind of things. I found it more convenient than tqdm for logging information: https://github.com/valentingol/logml

Comment: @ValentinGoldité, thank you! maybe you what to write a short answer with an example?